# How to format a presentation in ox-reveal / Reveal.js export in Org mode

Tags: org-export

Following are the list of default options for `Reveal.js`, which I got when I did `C-c C-e #`

```
#+OPTIONS: reveal_control:t reveal_height:-1
#+OPTIONS: reveal_history:nil reveal_keyboard:t reveal_overview:t
#+OPTIONS: reveal_progress:t reveal_rolling_links:nil
#+OPTIONS: reveal_single_file:nil reveal_slide_number:"c"
#+OPTIONS: reveal_title_slide:auto reveal_width:-1
#+REVEAL_MARGIN: -1
#+REVEAL_MIN_SCALE: -1
#+REVEAL_MAX_SCALE: -1
#+REVEAL_ROOT: file:///C:\Users\nd04805\Documents\99 EMACS\work\PPT\reveal.js
#+REVEAL_TRANS: none
#+REVEAL_SPEED: default
#+REVEAL_THEME: moon
#+REVEAL_EXTRA_CSS:
#+REVEAL_EXTRA_JS:
#+REVEAL_HLEVEL:
#+REVEAL_TITLE_SLIDE_BACKGROUND:
#+REVEAL_TITLE_SLIDE_BACKGROUND_SIZE:
#+REVEAL_TITLE_SLIDE_BACKGROUND_REPEAT:
#+REVEAL_TITLE_SLIDE_BACKGROUND_TRANSITION:
#+REVEAL_MATHJAX_URL: https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML
#+REVEAL_PREAMBLE:
#+REVEAL_HEAD_PREAMBLE:
#+REVEAL_POSTAMBLE:
#+REVEAL_MULTIPLEX_ID:
#+REVEAL_MULTIPLEX_SECRET:
#+REVEAL_MULTIPLEX_URL:
#+REVEAL_MULTIPLEX_SOCKETIO_URL:
#+REVEAL_SLIDE_HEADER: 
#+REVEAL_SLIDE_FOOTER:Process Automation
#+REVEAL_PLUGINS:
#+REVEAL_DEFAULT_FRAG_STYLE:
#+REVEAL_INIT_SCRIPT:
#+REVEAL_HIGHLIGHT_CSS: %r/lib/css/zenburn.css
```

I could edit a few of them to get some fancy slide show set up.

The following things what I'm looking for (which are rather basic) could not be found.

**1. How to set the title/author_name/email_address?**

I tried using the `#+TITLE` `#+AUTHOR` - but could not get it to work. [Reference](http://orgmode.org/manual/Document-title.html#Document-title)

**2. How to align text (at least left align)?**

I tried deleting `reveal_center:t` from the template - but no use

I'm using [Section 12.3](http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html#Export-settings) of Org manual as reference, but failing somehow to see it through.

Any pointers to lead me to the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 10):

The org-reveal export package builds on top of `ox-html`. That means that most export settings are still controlled just like when exporting org to html.

*How to set the title/author_name/email_address?*

To set the title, author name and email address you can **use the standard org-mode preprocessor tags**:

```
#+TITLE: My wonderful reveal presentation
#+DATE: 11.10.2016
#+AUTHOR: Me
#+EMAIL: me@me.com
```

You just have to place them at the top of your org document.

The information will land in the title screen when you export your org to reveal. To make sure they really get exported, you can [override any other configurations](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Export-settings) by adding the following line:

```
#+OPTIONS: author:t date:t email:t
```

*How to align text (at least left align)?*

Text alignment - be it left, right or whatever else - is controlled by adding [style attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_style.asp) to your html. The easiest way to achieve this is by writing your own **CSS stylesheet** and adding it to reveal with:

```
#+REVEAL_EXTRA_CSS: ./mystyle.css
```

An example of what you could write into a `mystyle.css` file to align text to the left is:

```
.reveal p {
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 55px;
}
```

Adding styles to your presentation is not the responsibility of ox-reveal, since it's job is to export org to html. That said, you can always inject your own HTML in a presentation, if you want extra control over a particular element. Here is an example to insert a video:

```
#+BEGIN_HTML
<video id="vid" onClick="playPause('vid');" width=38.3% height=38.3% autoplay>
    <source data-src="./media/vid.webm" type="video/webm" />
</video>
#+END_HTML
```

The function playPause is defined on a `vid.js` file and org-reveal is aware of it:

```
#+REVEAL_EXTRA_JS: { src: 'vid.js', async: true, condition: function() { return !!document.body.classList; } }
```